# In a mongoose Schema, how can I declare multiple properties with the same sub-properties at once?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a list of equipment slots for a RPG type character sheet. Each of the slots has a type like “head” or “body”, and each of them will have an object representing an item the character is wearing. Every piece of equipment will have the same variable types (as shown below) but I do not want to write each one separately because the list is very long. Is there a way to say “each of these types of equipment will have these variables”. Below is my attempt at it, but it doesn’t work (says “head is undefined”) or if I remove head (“body is undefined”) etc.

```
equipment: {
    head,
    body,
    legs,
    feet,
    shoulders,
    arms,
    hands,
    back,
    ringLeft,
    ringRight,
    neck,
    rightHand,
    leftHand,
    ammunition: {
      default: {
        name: {
          type: String,
          default: "Empty"
        },
        Type: {
          type: String,
          default: ""
        },
        subType: {
          type: String,
          default: ""
        },
        handling: {
          type: String,
          default: ""
        },
        rarity: {
          type: String,
          default: ""
        },
        durability: {
          max: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          current: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          }
        },
        damage: {
          min: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          max: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          }
        },
        armorClass: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
        },
        str: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
        },
        dex: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
        },
        int: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
        },
        accuracy: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
        },
        magicAccuracy: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
        },
        magicDefense: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
        },
        armorPiercing: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0
        },
        resistances: {
          fire: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          ice: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          lightning: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          water: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          earth: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          wind: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          light: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          },
          dark: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a sub-schema. It's just a normal mongoose-schema but you can declare attributes with that schema and so don't have to type all that stuff again.
test
So.. create a new Schema:

```
const schema_equipmentAttributes = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: "Empty"
    },
    Type: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    subType: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    }
});
```

Then you can declare:

```
equipment: {
    head: { type: schema_equipmentAttributes },
    body: { type: schema_equipmentAttributes },
    legs: { type: schema_equipmentAttributes },
    feet: { type: schema_equipmentAttributes }
}
```

This should be the easiest way :)